# Unity-child deforms when parent is rotated

Tags: unity-game-engine

Child changes geometry when i rotate the parent.
Parent is empty object and has scale (1, 1, 1).
Child is basic Capsule with adjusted rotation, position and scale.
I already tried deleting everything and i started over but nothing changed.
Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Could you send us a picture of this deformed object?

Comment: This usually means the scale of the object is not (1,1,1).